# Is this ('RV style' 16amp) -> (2 x 13amp) mains socket adapter dangerous? (2 x 13 being far more than 16)

Tags: current, mains

The 2 sockets are 13 amp rated, and whatever is plugged in would be fused with anything up to a 13amp fuse.

The blue 'RV' style wire/plug is 16amp rated. If either plug were to run over 13 amps they would break the respective fuse, but would it be dangerous then to have both be running current below 13 but which totalled more than 16? (say 10amps in both).

Would this mean then that without knowledge of what fuse/trips this was plugged into, then this product itself would be inherently dangerous?

[image: 240v Double Fly Lead, 16Amp Plug, 1m Long Extension Lead]

(Image source: [L&S Engineers - 240v Double Fly Lead, 16Amp Plug, 1m Long Extension Lead](https://www.lsengineers.co.uk/16amp-plug-to-13amp-double-socket-1m-fly-lead.html))

Comment: The 16 A plug should only be plugged into a circuit protected, by a fuse or breaker, to the lesser of 16 A and the blue cable rating. This is true regardless of what sockets are fed by the blue cable.

Answer (score 5):

It's no more dangerous than a regular extension cord with multiple sockets on the end.  The IEC receptacle should itself be on a fuse or circuit breaker that will interrupt an overcurrent condition for any of the receptacles attached to it.

Comment: Y6es, that does look like light-gauge wire to carry 26 amps. That said, it's a short wire, and should not drop a lot of voltage, and in the open, might be able to dissipate the heat generated.

Comment: Because this would be plugged into places I won't necessarily be checking, would it be best to install some kind of inline 16amp 230v breaker just to be safe?

Comment: Use an adaptor with a single socket. Then it'll be protected by the 13A fuse in whatever you plug into it, which could be a two way extension lead, four way or anything else you like.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 16A socket is correctly fused/breakered there is no danger.

13A sockets are commonly backed by much larger breakers than 13A (because the plugs used with them are fused)